# Can MS Project files containing sub-projects be syncronized with SharePoint 2013 task list?

Tags: 2013, task-list, ms-project

My end goal is to create a SharePoint list that contains multiple projects (Master and sub projects) created in and synchronized with MS Project.  We want to use SharePoint to manage the multiple projects my team is working on and use MS Power BI to create resource reports.

I have a project enabled SharePoint 2013 on premise site with a new project task list.  I have opened the list with MS Project and created a subproject by injecting another MS Project file.  When I try to save the file (which synchronizes it back to SharePoint) the sub project does not show up.  When I try to expand the sub project in SharePoint I get an error "We can't insert or expand this project. For projects stored on the web, save the master and subprojects separately, before inserting projects into the master."

I have tried creating the sub-projects as individual MS Project files synchronized with their own SharePoint tasks lists and then merging them into a new SharePoint list/master MS Project file but still get the same error.  I am going to try storing all the MS Project files in the SharePoint document library on the same site and see if that works.

In the mean time does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: I am running into the same issue with Project Pro and SharePoint Online. Were you ever able to find a solution that worked? Thank you in advance.